# Parsing dynamically growing web pages with jsoup

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm writing an Android app that parses a web page, filters the image links from it and load them in a `WebView`.

It works fine for static pages, but i have no idea how to handle pages that dynamically add content as i scroll down, such as [9gag](http://9gag.com/), [imgur](http://imgur.com/r/pics), Facebook etc.

Is there a solution for this? I guess the dynamic content is handled by JavaScript. Maybe there's a way to call this JavaScript code before parsing the page?

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try looking at the requests that dynamic pages make.
All of them use a pattern of dynamic pagination, or a cursor.
Imgur for example issues requests with an url like this.

https://imgur.com/gallery/hot/viral/page/4/hit?set=0

Where you specify the page and the set is the portion of the page (Normaly they go up to 3)